# Why does the assignment from a dynamic object throw a RuntimeBinderException?

Tags: c#

Why is this code throwing a RuntimeBinderException and how can I resolve this? Why cant I catch this exception in the catch block?

The same error also occurs if I use `System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(response)` to parse the json string.

```
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace DynamicDemo
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            String response = "{ \"data\":{ \"accountId\":\"YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID\"},\"message\":null}";
            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
            String account = obj.data.accountId;
            Console.WriteLine(account);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

}

And the output...

```
'DynamicDemo.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DynamicDemo.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'DynamicDemo.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DynamicDemo.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'DynamicDemo.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DynamicDemo.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Dynamic\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Dynamic.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
'DynamicDemo.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DynamicDemo.vshost.exe): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll   
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID
'DynamicDemo.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DynamicDemo.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CLIENTDIAGNOSTICS\XAMLDIAGNOSTICS\x86\WpfXamlDiagnosticsTap.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'DynamicDemo.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DynamicDemo.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop\7.1.40304.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'DynamicDemo.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DynamicDemo.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
```

Update 1:
Changed the exception handler to catch all exceptions but it made no difference

Comment: Your code works, though. It prints `YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID` in the output. Those exceptions are probably caught and dealt with inside JsonConvert.

Comment: The fact that we see the "YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID" output in the console makes me think that the exceptions may not be occurring in the code you have shown here. Have you tried stepping through it in the debugger?

Comment: It seems you would need to tell the method what class to deserialize the object to. I think you can do that either, by specifying the object type or as a type parameter to the DeserializeObject method. Also, have you checked that the RuntimeBinderException wasn't changed to another exception type while it was being bubbled up?

Comment: in your catch, do a writeline e.Message so we can see some details.

Comment: Tried that but the catch block is never executed even with a generic exception handler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all entirely normal.  Something you can see by forcing the debugger to stop on the first-chance exception.  An option you probably already have turned on by accident.

- 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'data'
- 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'accountId'
- Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

All of which are accurate.  You are seeing the DLR poking at *possible* ways to find the property back.  None of the obvious ways work, after the 2nd attempt it tries the `IDictionary<string, JToken>` interface that JObject implements.  Almost there except that the JToken value requires a cast.  The 4th attempt is good.

You don't have a real problem beyond the cost of those exceptions.  Which is strictly limited, you can call JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() again and note that you now **don't** get the exceptions.  The DLR has remembered the optimal strategy.

Everything works the way it should.